# Echo Wordpress Post featured image URL in the header

Tags: php, image, wordpress, url, header

I want to add the featured image URL of a post to the header. When a Facebook user shares a Wordpress page, this code in the header:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="FEATUREDIMAGEURL">
```

Will return a specific image for the share. However, I cannot figure out how to add the URL of the post's featured image... Can you?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, no?

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )); ?>
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Which image does that return?